# Are von Neumann entropies of complementary but physically distinct subsystems in time-dependent settings identical?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, quantum-entanglement, density-operator, time-evolution

We assume a quantum system AB with subsystems A and B and take the Schmidt decomposition of a state $\vert\psi_{AB}\rangle=\sum_i\lambda_i \vert a_i\rangle\vert b_i\rangle$ defined on the compsite Hilbert space. Reduced density matrices, $\rho_A$, and, $\rho_B$, of the subsystems lead then to identical von Neumann entropies, $S(\rho_A)=S(\rho_B)$ (cf. Breuer, Petruccione, p.75-78 for example), which allow for the study of entanglement of subsystems.

Is this statement also true for time-dependent problems at some fixed time $t_i$, where I initially have a product state, $\vert\psi_{AB}(t_0)\rangle=\vert \psi_A\rangle\vert\psi_B\rangle$, which is then subject to some dynamics due to a time-independent Hamiltonian $H=H_A+H_B+V_{AB}$, where $V_{AB}$ is an interaction term?

My motivation is as follows: Let's assume we have two physically distinct subsystems A and B, e.g. an anharmonic and a harmonic oscillator, which are subject to characteristic energy scales. The dynamics of subsystem A is then encoded in $\rho_A(t)=tr_b\{\vert\psi_{AB}(t)\rangle\langle\psi_{AB}(t)\vert$, with characteristic time scales. The same holds for B. When I now calculate the correspondings von Neumann entropies, I expect to recover those characteristic time-scales since the entropy is fully determined by the reduced density matrix, which encodes the dynamics of the subsystem. However, if A and B are physically distinct and their dynamics therefore subject to different characteristic time scales, I do not see how the equality of von Neumann entropies should hold for a certain fixed time $t_i$ as stated at the beginning of this post.

Comment: I don't know if I understand the question correctly, but note that as long as the time evolution is unitary, the purity of the overall state does not change and hence you should see that for each $t$, the reduced density matrices have the same non-zero eigenvalues.

Comment: Ok, that's an interesting point, since the overal state is always pure and the evolution unitary. But I would naivley expect that the reduced density matrices and therefore corresponding entropies somehow encode the natural dynamics of the subsystem interacting with its complement, and when the subsystems differ so would do the entropies. I feel like I still don't get the connection between the formal Schmidt decomposition result and "physical intuition" (if that's useful at all here)

Comment: Well, the "form" of the reduced density matrices will change, eventually. For example, here at the initial time your overall state is a product state and hence the reduced density matrices are pure; if the time evolution transforms the overall state in an entangled state, the reduced density matrices will be mixed. So the corresponding von Neumann entropies will change, too: from 0 to something non-zero; but since both matrices have the same non-zero eigenvalues at each time, their respective von Neumann entropies are the same at each time.